# Is there a name for this Javascript snippet "Promise.resolve().then(....)"?

Tags: javascript, promise, terminology

Since I have encountered the construct:

```
var variable = Promise.resolve().then(function(){
    //
    // do usefull stuff
    //
    return result;
});
```

frequently and, because it seems to have some distinct usage to some similar but different:

```
var variable = Promise.resolve((function(){
    //
    // do usefull stuff
    //
    return result;
})());
```

and mostly because I have seem it having been used so often, as sort of a Promise-chain-started, being somwhat a *short-hand* of this more explicit *long-hand* code:

```
var variable = new Promise((resolve) => { 
    resolve(()=>{
        // 
        // do usefull stuff
        //
        return result;
    }); 
});
```

I would very much be happy to know how other people refer to it? Is it called a Promise-Chain-Head, or maybe a Function-To-Promise-Chain-Integrator, or is there even a name?

I consider having/knowing the name of this construct, helpful to communicate its difference to the second version of the mere "Convert Argument To Promise" `Promise.resolve()` construct?

Bonus: 
Regarding the difference of both initial constructs, I assume the main is that the second version would not handle any Errors/Exceptions in the unified "transform to Promise rejects"-fashion as does the first Promise-Chain-Head.

Comment: It's just code.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is no direct name for `Promise.resolve().then` but this pattern is typically represented with `Promise.try`.

[`Promise.try`](https://github.com/tc39/proposal-promise-try) which we [have at bluebird](http://bluebirdjs.com/docs/api/promise.try.html) that is still a Stage 1 JavaScript proposal (meaning it has not been adopted or implemented in browsers yet).

You can polyfill it with:

```
if (typeof Promise.try !== 'function') {
    Promise.try = {
        try(func) {
            if (typeof this !== 'function') {
                throw new TypeError('Receiver must be a constructor');
            }
            return new this(function (resolve) {
                resolve(func());
            });
        }
    }.try;
}
```

And then use it:

```
Promise.try(() => {
  // same as Promise.resolve().then(...
});
```

Or you can use an async function:

```
(async () => { // errors here are converted to rejections

})();
```

Since async/await became popular this has generally become less of an issue since async functions automatically turn thrown errors to rejections.

Comment: @mhodges the answer is coherent to the question title itself. How is it unrelated to the question? The op asked if there is any name of the said pattern, the answer explains if there is any and why, what's wrong with it?

Comment: `Promise.try = { try (func) { ... } }.try` It honestly took me a minute to notice the object literal there. I initially thought you were using some sort of hypothetical ESnext syntax for a `try` block with an argument :P I can't say I've ever seen that pattern before for named functions. Usually I'd just go for a `function try (func) { ... }`

Comment: @PatrickRoberts that code is copied from the polyfill, the reason it's done this way is to support promise subclassing. It's a bit clever in my taste.

Comment: @BenjaminGruenbaum I don't understand what `{ try (func) { ... } }.try` accomplishes that `function try (func) { ... }` doesn't. They both support subclassing.

Comment: @PatrickRoberts actually you're right. I was confused (and wrong) - and it's because of a technicality in naming `try` is a reserved word. You can't do `Promise.try = function try(...)` because try is a reserved word and in addition you need (for spec compliance) for the `.name` property to be `try`. This is a way to overcome this.

Comment: I suppose I should have `tried` it before making a dumb comment about its purpose :P